# How to find attenuation constant

Tags: passive-networks, transmission-line

Propagation constant is in the form
 P= a+jb (a= attenuation constant b = phase constant) 
a +jb = ln (x+ jy). 
How do I separate the real and imaginary part in the RHS so that I can equate the attenuation constant and phase constant to it?

Answer (score 2):

How about this.
$$a+jb=\ln(x+jy)$$
$$e^{a+jb} = x+jy$$
$$e^a\angle b = x+jy$$

Now it is just a matter of converting the coordinates.

$$a=\ln{(x^2+y^2)}$$
$$b=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$